# Output of a Java program

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to run a program where I have created 3 threads.

1) Apple.Java

```
package Test;
import java.util.Random;

public class Apple implements Runnable{

    String name;
    int time;
    Random r = new Random();

    public Apple(String s){

        name = s;
        time = r.nextInt(999);
    }

    public void run(){

        try{
            System.out.printf("%s is sleeping for %d\n", name, time);
            //because we want each thread to sleep for random time.
            Thread.sleep(time);
            System.out.printf("%s is done\n" + name);

        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

2) ThreadTest.java

```
package Test;

public class Anand {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Apple("one"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Apple("two"));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Apple("three"));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

**Expected output is**

```
one is sleeping for 934
three is sleeping for 383
two is sleeping for 228
two is done.
three is done.
one is done.
```

**Actual output is :**

When I am running "ABC.java" as Java application I am getting following output :

```
one is sleeping for 934
three is sleeping for 383
two is sleeping for 228
```

Here I am not able to understand why below statement is not getting executed? or why i am not getting output of the below statement on console?

```
 System.out.printf("%s is done\n" + name);
```

Comment: Rather than a blank exception handler, try outputting any exceptions.

Comment: I.e. `main` is completing before your threads can finish.

Comment: @Andy Turner but when I debug the code the program control is going to that System.out.printf("%s is done\n" + name); statement, however it is not getting printed on cosole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual bug in this code is:

```
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
```

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/jSzD1I)

Because this:

```
System.out.printf("%s is done\n" + name);
```

should be:

```
System.out.printf("%s is done\n", name);
```

Please consider this be an illustrative example of why empty catch blocks should *rarely* (if ever) be used.

```
}catch(Exception e){}  // Aaaargh! Nope nope nope.
```

At a minimum, print the stack trace:

```
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

But also, make sure that you wait for the threads to complete:

```
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

This is more of a good habit (akin to closing streams) than something necessary for this particular example.

[From the Javadoc of `Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

OP's code doesn't invoke `exit`, so that's not relevant here. All of the threads are non-daemon threads, so execution will continue until they've all finished (somehow). In other words, the JVM will implicitly inserts a `join()` to wait for all threads to complete. As such, *only* inserting a `join`, as suggested in other answers, doesn't actually do anything to change the behavior of the code.

Comment: Understood, will surely take care going forward, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

System.out.printf("%s is done\n" + name);

replace the above line  with  System.out.printf("%s is done\n" , name);

Now it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This because the `main` method in `ThreadTest.java` file stops execution when all the statements in its body have been executed. Since it is the main thread, when `main` stops execution all the other thread are stopped.

Use `join()` in `main` to keep it waiting until all the threads are completed.

So your corrected code in `ThreadTest.java` should be:

```
package theNewBostonTuts;

public class Anand {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Apple("one"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Apple("two"));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Apple("three"));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
}
```

**Note:** There is also problem with use of `System.out.printf` method in `Apple.Java` file. Use `System.out.printf("%s is done\n", name);` instead of `System.out.printf("%s is done\n" + name);`

Comment: If you fix the error with the `System.out.printf`, you don't need to join: https://ideone.com/YgY7gz. This doesn't actually fix the problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree that there is also problem with line `System.out.printf`. But I'm SURE that the problem will not resolve without using `join()`

Comment: I'm sure that if you looked at the linked ideone snippet, you'd see that it works without the join, for the reasons I mention in my answer.

Comment: It may work few times or some _specific environment_, but not in general.

Comment: yes, in general. From [`Thread`'s Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html): "The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs: ... All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.".

Answer (score 1):

Main is completing before your threads finish.
You will need to use Thread.join to wait for each of them to finish.

i.e.
...

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

...

see https://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example for more information

Comment: If you fix the error with the `System.out.printf`, you don't need to join: https://ideone.com/YgY7gz. This doesn't actually fix the problem.